# Calculus Inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am thinking about the following problem:

Suppose $1 \le f(x) \le 2$ on $[0,1]$.  Let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be fixed points such that $0< x_0 <x_1< 1$.  Show that there exist positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that $a \le g(x_1)/g(x_2) \le b$ whenever $g(x)$ is positive on $[0,1]$ and $(f(x)g'(x))'=0$.

If $f(x)$=1, then $g(x)$ is harmonic and this problem would be solved by the Harnarck inequality.  However, for the given $f(x)$, I am not sure how to approach this.

Any help with this would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: In other words, $f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x)=0$ as the constraint, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of taking a PDE result into one dimension and turning it into a calculus problem. Life's easy in one dimension.

We have $f(x)g'(x)\equiv C$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$. Hence $C\le g'\le C/2$. Integration yields 
$$g(0)+\frac{C}{2}x\le g(x)\le g(0)+Cx$$
Hence, in any compactly contained interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset (0,1)$, 
$$\sup_{[\alpha,\beta]} g \le g(0)+C\beta, \quad \inf_{[\alpha,\beta]} g \ge g(0)+C\alpha/2$$
And since
$$g(0)+C\beta \le \frac{2\beta}{\alpha} ( g(0)+C\alpha/2)
$$
the claim follows.